# Mr of Acid getting wrong answer

Tags: homework, physical-chemistry

I am preparing for A level chemistry exams. One of the questions I came across is

> Calculate the $M_\mathrm r$ of unknown monoprotic acid. The volume is $15\,\rm cm^3$ and concentration $10.95\,\rm g\cdot dm^{-3}$.

I know how to calculate the number of moles and I know the equation to calculate $M_\mathrm r$ but could anyone give me some guidance on how to calculate the mass from this data?

Comment: @Ivan please note that units should be upright, not slanted. Thanks for the edits. :)

Comment: Is it not just $10.95 \times 15/1000$? The concentration is in $\rm g\cdot dm^{-3}$.

Comment: @surelyourejoking You would, after that, have to divide by the number of moles.

Comment: @orthocresol Indeed. Is it possible to find that given the information?

Comment: @surelyourejoking No, not the information we are given, at least. But OP mentioned that they knew "how to calculate the number of miles", so I'm guessing there's an earlier part of the question that they hid from us.

Comment: @surelyourejoking do you mean you have to divide it by the number of moles to get the mass of substance or to calculate the Mr? because you can get the number of moles this way: n = volume x concentration ,so no i'm not hiding anything

Comment: In this case, I don't think n = CV is correct. That would be correct if concentration were given, as it normally is, in moles per decimetre cubed. However, in this case it is given in grammes per dm$^3$, so in fact, concentration x volume gives the mass.

Answer (score 1):

The concentration of your acid is given as a [mass concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(chemistry)).

Without knowing the [molar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass), the [molar concentration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration) and the [amount of substance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amount_of_substance) in a volume of $15~\mathrm{cm}^{-3}$ are not accessible.

However, knowing that

$\mathrm{1~L = 1~dm^{-3} = 1000~cm^{-3}}$

and therefore

$15~\mathrm{cm}^{-3} = 0.015~\mathrm{dm}^{-3}$

the mass of the acid (in $15~\mathrm{cm}^{-3}$) is given as

$m = 10.95~\mathrm{g\,dm^{−3}\cdot0.015~\mathrm{dm}^{-3} = 0.16425~g}$